# How to write and access function in React stateless components

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I want to write and access function/const in CSS style with stateless React Component.

I did below implementation but can't get success:

```
const MyComponent = ({ title, data }: Props) => {
  function setPercentageColor() {
    console.log("standard");
    return "#ca2626";
  }
  const percentage = "50";
  return (
    <div className="progress-circle">
      <CircularProgressbar
        percentage={percentage}
        text={percentage}
        styles={{
          root: {},
          path: {
            stroke: "#0080a6",
            strokeWidth: "8",
            transition: "stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease 0s"
          },
          trail: {
            stroke: setPercentageColor //here I want to access
          },
          text: {
            fill: "#28323c",
            fontSize: "35px",
            fontFamily: "Roboto Regular"
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```

Please help in to write the correct solution.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, mentioned in the question. Want to access in CSS style

Comment: How do you use it in your `CircularProgressbar` component? You can access your function just by invoking it right there. `stroke: setPercentageColor()`

Comment: It's work, thanks @devserkan

Comment: You are welcome. Let me provide a simple answer.

Comment: @devserkan Thanks for the solution, please upvote as it'll help to beginners :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your function directly by calling it. ie:

```
stroke: setPercentageColor()
```

Here is a simple working example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const setTextColor = () => "#ca2626";
  return (
    <div>
      <Foo
        styles={{ colors: { text: setTextColor(), background: "black" } }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const Foo = (props) => {
  const { styles } = props;
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        color: styles.colors.text,
        backgroundColor: styles.colors.background,
      }}
    >
      Foo
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```